# IOS 14 UIButton placeholder

Tags: ios, ios14

I faced some kind of bug, i have a UIButton with no title & placeholder and with Image in it, created in storyboard. When i set my project target to IOS 15.0 everything looks right, but when i change it to 14.0, by button has Image and placeholder "Button", how can i get rid of this placeholder ? [Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WczZd.png)] [app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP9SO.png)]

In button properties in storyboard there is no placeholder set.

Comment: button->type->custom - may be this will help

Comment: @Nikita no, same issue :(